# I have issues getting my ruby code to run

Tags: ruby

I am trying to pull RFID tag information from an Impinj Speedway reader through tcpip. To access the info from the reader, I must go through HTTPS and a specific port. My code:

```
require 'socket'

# The IP address or hostname of your reader 
READER_HOSTNAME = 'https://10.57.237.50'
# The TCP port specified in Speedway Connect
READER_PORT = 14150

# Create a TCP socket connection to the reader 
s = TCPSocket.open('https://10.57.237.50', 14150)
# Receive data in an infinite loop
while true
  # Read one line at a time
  line = s.gets 
  # Print it to the screen
  print line      
end
```

This appears to run but, never completes. Ruby hangs at a flashing cursor. I think it has something to do with the port and maybe even the secure HTTP.

Comment: What do you mean by never completes? Does it not print anything? You have an infinite while loop, so I wouldn't expect the program to actually terminate.

Comment: `while true` will never terminate.

Comment: "I am not a programmer by any means" - That's crap. You have written code (or are attempting to), therefor you are a programmer. Don't count yourself out because you are new.

Comment: Shouldn't `TCPSocket.open('https://10.57.237.50', 14150)` be failing? I'm pretty sure the host name there is not supposed to include a protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you have an infinite loop.

```
while true # This runs FOREVER (or at least until ctrl-c)
  # Read one line at a time
  line = s.gets 
  # Print it to the screen
  print line      
end
```

You really should change it to be:

```
while line = s.gets # Read one line at a time
  # Print it to the screen
  print line      
end
```

This will read every line that was printed to the socket, and then end when you run out of lines. Finally, you will need to remember to close the socket at the end.

```
s.close
```

If you want a little more reading to do, check out the [Ruby documentation on sockets](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html) That has some simple examples like yours.

Comment: I made changes per the post by jkeuhlen but, it still hangs at the cursor.

Comment: I am using textmate to write the code and the 14150 is highlighted in red and that is why I think it is a port issue

Comment: Is there anything going in to the socket? Read up on how sockets work in general. If it is hanging now, that is because it is waiting for something to come in to the socket (thats what `gets` is doing, waiting for input). As soon as you feed something to that socket, it will print it out then the program will end.

Comment: @jkeuhlen the change you proposed, it won't make any difference. Seems that he's not getting any input at all, that's his primary problem.

Answer (score 0):

With assistance from Impinj support, we discovered there was a bug in the Speedway Connect where if there were more antenna ports selected than were available (All are selected by default) the program hangs. In my configuration (4 ports on the Reader + (2) antenna Hubs) Ports: 1-8+9-16+17+25. Thanks to all that tried to help.